# Error compiling after referencing a dll to an application

Tags: c++

I have created these projects separately and compiled successfully.

1. MyApp - MyApp.exe
2. Mydll - Mydll.dll 'It has s dialoguebox.Simple.

I want io include this dll to the app so that I can instantiate obj and call methods of the dll from the app. This is what I want to do.

### Steps so far

I have put the name of lib in

> Project Properties->Linker->Input->Addtional Dependencies
>
> Tools->Option->Project and Solution->VC++->Library Files

put the path where the library files were (**do I need to put the path of the debug folder where the dll/lib contains or I can copy the dll/lib to different folder and put this path?**)

```
Tools->Option->Project and Solution->VC++->Include files
```

put the path of the header file of the dll/lib

All this done!

---

### Compiler error

> error C2065: 'IDD_DIALOG_CRINV' : undeclared identifier" IDD_DIALOG_CRINV is the dialogbox in the dll

---

I cannot figure out why this error occurs?is this something related to resource files? Do I need to reference somewhere the resource file?

After fix this, how can I create a instance of the dll and call the `messagebox`?

Is it something like below?
I create a event for `button_click` on the `application.exe`;

```
void CApp::OnBnClickedCreateDLLDlg(){
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CCReateDLLDlg test;
    test.domodal();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that your application source file does not have include of an h-file where your constants from the DLL project are defined.